# How can I create a Custom ExpandableListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an ArrayList called balances, inside balances I have an object and another ArrayList that I need to display as the next image will show you.

In the Image, Transactions are formed for a listView where each one has 6 text view showing the transactions attributes.

```
private String userID ;
private String time ;
private String date ;
private String transactionStatusCode ;
private String referenceID ;
private String amountAfterTax ;
private String description;
```

[image]

I read about ExpandableListView, but all example shows String arrays. As you will see in my code I have a Transaction Object that I need to show.
[image]

The Objects are formed from the follow JSON

```
   [{
    "guest": {
        "surname": "BENETOIDE A.1",
        "guestID": "004"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "userID": "AO15",
        "time": "0600",
        "date": "20161216",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "83366",
        "amountAfterTax": "300.00",
        "description": "RESTAURANT"
    }, {
        "userID": "AO15",
        "time": "0600",
        "date": "20161216",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "83654",
        "amountAfterTax": "100.62",
        "description": "RESTAURANT"
    }, {
        "userID": "AO15",
        "time": "05331",
        "date": "20161217",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "8329",
        "amountAfterTax": "100.62",
        "description": "ROOM SERVICE"
    }, {
        "userID": "S1PR",
        "time": "14554",
        "date": "20170107",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "2524",
        "amountAfterTax": "636.93",
        "description": "ROOM SERVICE"
    }]
}, {
    "guest": {
        "surname": "ALDITOY A.0",
        "guestID": "005"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "userID": "AO15",
        "time": "0510",
        "date": "20161222",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "94257",
        "amountAfterTax": "300.00",
        "description": "ROOM SERVICE"
    }, {
        "userID": "AO15",
        "time": "0510",
        "date": "20161222",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "92355",
        "amountAfterTax": "33.54",
        "description": "ROOM SERVICE"
    },  {
        "userID": "GT10",
        "time": "1405",
        "date": "20170109",
        "transactionStatusCode": "Committed",
        "referenceID": "19260",
        "amountAfterTax": "302.00",
        "description": "RESTAURANT"
    }]
}]
```

I create a Class called BalanceAdapter that extends from BaseExpandableListAdapter where I tried to show the items as I usually do when I extend from ArrayAdapter

```
package com.softwareengineerandroid.davidmata.coreclasses.Balance;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.softwareengineerandroid.davidmata.armletpaymentpilot.R;
import com.softwareengineerandroid.davidmata.coreclasses.transaction.Transaction;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by davidmata on 18/03/2017.
 */

public class BalanceAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> expanableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Transaction>> expandableListDatails;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public BalanceAdapter(Context context, List<Balance> listBalance){
    inflater=    (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    expanableListTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    expandableListDatails = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, ArrayList<Transaction>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int i=0;
    for (Balance balance:listBalance) {
        expanableListTitle.add(balance.getGuest().getSurname());

        map.put(balance.getGuest().getSurname()+i,(ArrayList<Transaction>) balance.getTransactions());
        i++;//evita ducplicacion de nombre de huespedes.
    }
    this.expandableListDatails = (HashMap)map;



}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDatails.get(this.expanableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_balance_item,null);
    }
    Transaction transaction =(Transaction) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    TextView tv_description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listBalance_description);
    TextView tv_referenceID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listBalance_referenceID);
    TextView tv_amount = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listBalance_amount);
    TextView tv_currencycode = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listBalance_currencyCode);
    TextView tv_date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listBalance_date);
    TextView tv_time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listBalance_time);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
}

This is my **list_balance_item.xml**.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBalance_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="SERVICE ROOM"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBalance_amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="$850.63"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBalance_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="18/AGO/2017"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBalance_time"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="12:08"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBalance_currencyCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CurrencyCode: MXN"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBalance_referenceID"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Feference : 1671"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_balance.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.softwareengineerandroid.davidmata.armletpaymentpilot.FragmentBalance">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/fragBalance_expListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentBalace.java,** where I should set the Adapter.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_balance, container, false);
    ListView balanceList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragBalance_listview);
    ArrayList<Balance> arrayList = null;
    try {
        arrayList = (ArrayList<Balance>) new BalanceController(new BalanceFromApiJson()).getBalance(getContext(),"http://192.168.1.100:50591/api/Balance?reservationID=45454655465");
        BalanceAdapter balanceAdapter = new BalanceAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   // TransationAdapter balanceAdapter = new         TransationAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
   // balanceList.setAdapter(balanceAdapter);


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend for you to Search about how to use `ExpandableListView` 
or check this link of it's decoumentaion [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Thanks, now I am going to change the question, asking about  ExpandableListView